# Merging cells on table: error

Tags: tables

I'm want to merge twon cells of the same line on a table. I found in previous questions the multicolumn command, but it doesn't compile and I can't figure what is wrong with my code. Do I need a package? Couldn't find one. There goes the code..

`\begin{frame}{Discussão: Fisiologia do andar medular}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
        \centering
        \textbf{Lesão em NMS} & \textbf{Lesão em NMI} \\
         & \\
        \pause
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Perda da atividade motora voluntária}\\% & Perda da atividade motora voluntária\\
        \pause
        Hiperreflexia & Hiporreflexia \\
        \pause
        Hipertonia & Hipotonia \\
        \pause
        Atrofia musc por desuso & Atrofia musc por denervação \\
        \pause
        Paralisia espástica & Paralisia flácida \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}`

the error message when compiling:

! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ^^@-\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.260   \end{frame}

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `\pause` before the line break as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Discussão: Fisiologia do andar medular}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
        \centering
        \textbf{Lesão em NMS} & \textbf{Lesão em NMI} \\
         & \pause\\ %%pause before linebreak
         \multicolumn{2}{c}{Perda da atividade motora voluntária}\\% & Perda da atividade motora voluntária\\
        \pause
        Hiperreflexia & Hiporreflexia \\
        \pause
        Hipertonia & Hipotonia \\
        \pause
        Atrofia musc por desuso & Atrofia musc por denervação \\
        \pause
        Paralisia espástica & Paralisia flácida \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```